# HTML form onsubmit passing this.id; yielding unexpected value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a website and was experiencing this problem, so I simplified it as much as possible.

index.html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>

    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="log(this.id)">
        <input name="id">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
function log(str){
    console.log("str=" + str);
}
```

When I submit the form, I see this:

> str=[object HTMLInputElement]

and when I change the value of name to anything but "id", I see the expected

> str=myForm

I get the exact same behavior if I switch all instances of "name" and "id" in the code. In other words, it doesn't seem to be a particular limitation of either attribute, but something more general.

I'm running MAMP on OS X 10.8; experiencing problem in Firefox 22.0 and Chrome ver. 28.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.id` on form elements accesses form fields by their name. To get the ID attribute use `this.getAttribute('id')`.

Answer (score 0):

When you gave the input the name "id", log(this.id) translates to log(myForm.id) where id is a property of myForm, it is in fact the input child element. This is indicated by the [object HTMLInputElement] class name which appears.

When you name the input child control to something else this.id now refers to the forms id attribute.

The same logic applies when you switch "id" with "name" since you can refer to controls by either their name or id.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's because `this.id` is being interpreted as "*the element with name `id` that belongs to the form*", that's why you're receiving an [object HTMLInputElement] through the parameter. When there is no such input (i.e. when you name it differently), `this.id` is interpreted as *the form id*.